# How to remove all stopwords from each line of string using the weka.core.Stopwords java class

Tags: java

I have a string in such format

```js
String wordTyp = "i love to bake you a good sandwitch \n"
    + "and i love biscuit and you? \n";
```

How would I remove every stop words in the line of the strings, using weka.core.Stopwords in java?

```js
public String removeStopWords(String word,int OriginCount){
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(word);
  
  StringBuilder wordDocNoStopWord = new StringBuilder();
  
  String lineOfText =""; int lineCount = 0;
  
  Stopwords checker = new Stopwords();
  while (scanner.hasNextLine() && lineCount < OriginCount){
    lineOfText = scanner.nextLine() + " \n";
   
   if(checker.is(lineOfText)){/// confirms a stopword in here
     checker.clear(); ///and clears any stopwords in that line
   }
   lineCount++;
   wordDocNoStopWord.append(new StringBuilder(lineOfText));
    System.out.printf(lineOfText);
  }
  scanner.close();
  
  
  
  
  return wordDocNoStopWord.toString();
 }
```

Comment: whats a stopword

Comment: list of words that are very common in a document that won't make the document classifiable. example the, is, a etc

Comment: u can simply do split on "space" and process words in a list

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this: (I dont have access to a compiler so it may require minor fixes)

```
public String removeStopWords(String word,int OriginCount){
String delim = " ";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(word.split(delim)));

Stopwords checker = new Stopwords();

for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){
        c = list.get(i);
        temp = c.getText();

        if(checker.is(temp)){
            list.remove(i);
            i--;                
        }       
}

String listAsString = "";

for (String temp : list)
{
    listAsString += temp + " ";
}
    return listAsString;
}
```

Comment: what type is c and temp?